# Regex for detecting struts `.do` pages - tests failing

Tags: java, regex

I am testing the following regex that exists in an older project I have inherited:
`.*\\.do`

Within Java, the regex is declared as:

```
private static final String[] ACCESS_REGEX = {".*\\.do", ""};
```

And is essentially checked using the wrapper for Pattern.matches method: `value.matches(check)`.

This old regex is working fine for various incoming requests such as `home.do` and I am doing a test on various regex test sites (listed below):

- http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html
- http://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html

However, I can't see to get the regex to match various strings that I believe should match...  I thought the regex above matches Strings that end with `.do` and have some characters in front. However, when I test for these no matches are found.

[image]

### Example Test Strings:

```
home.do
\home.do
mmm\mmm\home.do
\mmm\home.do
 home.do
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remind the special meaning, the `\` character has in regular expressions *and* in Java string literals!

The regular expression should be

```
.*\.do
```

This works very well on http://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html.

In a Java string literal you also need to escape the `\` character, hence the regular expression in Java must be

```
.*\\.do
```

Comment: Thanks... you're completely right. Didn't drink enough coffee today :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the online regex tools you're using expect plain regex (without special characters escaped), which is `.*\.do` in your particular case - mind the single backslash.

On the other hand, when defined in a string literal in Java, regexes need special characters escaped, hence `".*\\.do"` in your Java code.

Use unescaped regexes in the online test tools.

Answer (score 0):

you need single back slash rather than double back slash in regexp. 
You want to escape the dot only. remove the first back slash and the tests will pass